# Obtain Specific values from challonge.com json file into ArrayList using gson

Tags: java, json, arraylist, nullpointerexception, gson

I'm attempting get to specific values from a JSON file from challonge.com (More info on http://api.challonge.com/v1/documents/participants/index). The values that I am trying to get are "id" and "name".

This is my current code.

```
  HttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();

  HttpGet request = new HttpGet(jsonUrl);

    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if(entity != null){
            //Allows me to search through the Participant Object using the 
            //Participant/Participants POJO
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().
                    registerTypeAdapter(Participant.class, new MyDeserializer<>()).
                    create();
            ContentType contentType = ContentType.getOrDefault(entity);
            Charset charset = contentType.getCharset();
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent(), charset);

            /*Goes through seperate JSON files received from the Challonge API.
            */
            ArrayList<Participant> al = new ArrayList<>();


            Type type = new TypeToken<List<Participant>>(){}.getType();
            ArrayList<Participant> list = gson.fromJson(reader, al.getClass());
```

I've also used the type variable instead of al.getClass(), but both give me the error of java.lang.NullPointerException whenever I decide to check the id and names as such:

```
 System.out.println(list.get(0).getPlayerId() + ": " + list.get(0).getPlayerName());
```

Also here is my Participant class

```
public class Participant {

   private String id;
   private String name;

   public String getPlayerId(){
       return id;
   }

   public String getPlayerName(){
       return name;
   }
}
```

And here is an example of some json code

```
[
  {
    "participant": {
     "active": true,
     "checked_in_at": null,
     "created_at": "2015-01-19T16:54:40-05:00",
     "final_rank": null,
     "group_id": null,
     "icon": null,
     "id": 16543993,
     "invitation_id": null,
     "invite_email": null,
     "misc": null,
     "name": "Participant #1",
     "on_waiting_list": false,
     "seed": 1,
     "tournament_id": 1086875,
     "updated_at": "2015-01-19T16:54:40-05:00",
     "challonge_username": null,
     "challonge_email_address_verified": null,
     "removable": true,
     "participatable_or_invitation_attached": false,
     "confirm_remove": true,
     "invitation_pending": false,
     "display_name_with_invitation_email_address": "Participant #1",
     "email_hash": null,
     "username": null,
     "attached_participatable_portrait_url": null,
     "can_check_in": false,
     "checked_in": false,
     "reactivatable": false
   }
 },
 {
   "participant": {
     "active": true,
     "checked_in_at": null,
     "created_at": "2015-01-19T16:54:43-05:00",
     "final_rank": null,
     "group_id": null,
     "icon": null,
     "id": 16543994,
     "invitation_id": null,
     "invite_email": null,
     "misc": null,
     "name": "Participant #2",
     "on_waiting_list": false,
     "seed": 2,
     "tournament_id": 1086875,
     "updated_at": "2015-01-19T16:54:43-05:00",
     "challonge_username": null,
     "challonge_email_address_verified": null,
     "removable": true,
     "participatable_or_invitation_attached": false,
     "confirm_remove": true,
     "invitation_pending": false,
     "display_name_with_invitation_email_address": "Participant #2",
     "email_hash": null,
     "username": null,
     "attached_participatable_portrait_url": null,
     "can_check_in": false,
     "checked_in": false,
     "reactivatable": false
      }
   }
 ]
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up finding a method that worked for me.

```
    HttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(jsonUrl);

    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if(entity != null){
            //Allows me to search through the Participant Object using the 
            //Participant/Participants POJO
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().
                    registerTypeAdapter(ParticipantWrapper.class, new MyDeserializer<>()).
                    create();
            ContentType contentType = ContentType.getOrDefault(entity);
            Charset charset = contentType.getCharset();
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent(), charset);

            /*Goes through seperate JSON files received from the Challonge API.
            */
            ArrayList<Participant> al = new ArrayList<>();

            JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
            JsonElement jsonElement = jsonParser.parse(reader);


           if(jsonElement.isJsonArray()){
               Iterator itor = jsonElement.getAsJsonArray().iterator();

               while(itor.hasNext()){
                   JsonObject jObject = (JsonObject) itor.next();
                   al.add(gson.fromJson(jObject.get("participant"), Participant.class));
               }
           }
            return al;
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TournamentInfo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your JSON is one level deeper than your Java object hierarchy. It does not contain a *list of participants* but a *list of things that each contain a participant*.

Try this:

```
public class ParticipantWrapper {
    public final Participant participant;

    public ParticipantWrapper {
        participant = null;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
 ArrayList<ParticipantWrapper> list = gson.fromJson(reader, new TypeToken<List<ParticipantWrapper>>(){}.getType());
```

and finally:

```
final String id = list.get(0).participant.getPlayerId();
```

**EDIT:** Please have a look at this complete and working example: https://gist.github.com/DavidMihola/2ee7740a2c0c22b016b4

Comment: I figured that it has something to do with that. I made the changes, but I still continue to get  NullPointerException

Comment: That's weird... I just saw that you have the line `registerTypeAdapter(Participant.class, new MyDeserializer<>())` in there - what does `MyDeserializer` do? Have you tried it without that line?

Comment: Also, what's `null`? The list itself? The item at index 0? Or the participant wrapped in that item?

Comment: its supposed to register a type adapter for a collection.class and then map each of the array member to appropriate objects. I just changed it to ParticipantWrapper.class instead, but that also failed, and also changed the      

     `ArrayList<ParticipantWrapper> list = gson.fromJson(reader, new TypeToken<List<ParticipantWrapper>>(){}.getType());`

to 

     `>ArrayList<ParticipantWrapper> list = new Gson().fromJson(reader, new TypeToken<List<ParticipantWrapper>>(){}.getType());`

But that also gave me a null pointer

Comment: Also the list itself is null

Comment: I ended up finding another way to work with is using JsonParser and JsonElement. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I still think that the error was actually in `MyDeserializer` - I've posted a gist of a complete example that uses your `Participant`, my `ParticipantWrapper` and an out-of-the-box `Gson`.